# Multiple Views in iPad

Tags: cocoa-touch, uisplitviewcontroller, uisplitview

Trying to open a second detail view from a detail view controller in a split view controller.

Not even having any luck amending Apple's MultipleDetailViews sample project.

```
-(IBAction)subViewButtonClicked
{
    UIViewController <SubstitutableDetailViewController> *detailViewController = nil;

    SubDetailViewController *subDetailViewContoller = [[SubDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SubDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    detailViewController = subDetailViewContoller;

    // Update the split view controller's view controllers array.
    NSArray *viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.navigationController, detailViewController, nil];
    splitViewController.viewControllers = viewControllers;

    [viewControllers release];   
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: subDetailViewContoller does not get displayed.

Answer (score 0):

[The example project](http://www.cimgf.com/2010/05/24/fixing-the-uisplitviewcontroller-template/) allowed the reuse of xibs and views to fix my issue perfectly.